# How to play an album starting at a specific track?

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediaquery

My app uses an MPMusicPlayerController to play music.
I'm getting a bit lost in all the documentation for it and MPMediaQuery and so on.

What I want to do is play a particular album, beginning at a specific track.

I can construct a MPMediaQuery that reruns the album, but how do I start playback at the specific track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you have the query, I'm assuming you already have a MPMediaItemCollection that you'd like to play. From there, you assign that collection as the player's queue, and a specific MPMediaItem from the collection as the player's now playing item. The collection declares an `items` property that allows you to access the individual media items by index, which you can use to assign the now playing item. In this case `0` will play the first track in the collection, but this can be set to any index within the array's bounds.

```
MPMusicPlayerController *controller = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];

[controller setQueueWithItemCollection:myMediaItemCollection];
[controller setNowPlayingItem:myMediaItemCollection.items[0]];

[controller prepareToPlay];
[controller play];
```

Comment: Yes - I have the query and MPMediaItemCollection all done. Thanks for the solution. It's funny how obvious this stuff is once you know.